# iSingleResult row count

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I use LINQ in my web app.
I get back an iSingleResult result sequence.
I was wondering how I get the number of return rows in the sequence.
If I do:

```
if (FooterC.Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (sp_GetFooterCResult dataRow in FooterC)
            {
                FooterText.Value = dataRow.ExtraText;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FooterText.Value = "";
        }
```

I get an error:
"The query results cannot be enumerated more than once."

How do I check how many rows were returned in the sequence?

The LINQ code as requested:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.sp_GetFooterC")]
public ISingleResult<sp_GetFooterCResult> sp_GetFooterC([Parameter(Name="Relevant", DbType="NVarChar(50)")] string relevant)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), relevant);
    return ((ISingleResult<sp_GetFooterCResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Comment: would you please show the code around that line?

Comment: Sure. Sorry. Edited the post.

Comment: could you show the query expression for FooterC as well? because as far as this code is concerned, it should work...

Comment: The linq code or the T-SQL of the stored procedure?

Comment: the linq code. However, I suspect that calling the SP is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
FooterText.Value = "";
foreach (var dataRow in FooterC)
{
   FooterText.Value = dataRow.ExtraText;
}
```

You don't need to check for Length or Count when you use foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restructure your code as follows? [Based on [Femaref's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289242/isingleresult-row-count/5289398#5289398)]:

```
var footerList = FooterC.ToList();

if (footerList.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var dataRow in footerList)
                {
                    FooterText.Value = dataRow.ExtraText;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FooterText.Value = "";
            }
```

Comment: Yep. Did not work. Still the same error. btw: for a list count is a property and not a method.